# PPT to Image Converting Concept

Tags: php, html

I Would like to implement below the code for making the ppt to html slide but this code is working only in localhost but if I put in my cpanel server, its shows "com" related error.

I have used following code

```
 $filepath= $_GET['File_name'];
    $ppApp = new COM("PowerPoint.Application");
    $ppApp->Visible = True;
    $strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]))); // C:/AppServ/www/myphp
    $FileName = "ppt_images";
    //$ppName = "MySlides.ppt";
    $ppName=$strPath."/MyPP/".$filepath;

    //*** Open Document ***//
    $ppApp->Presentations->Open(realpath($ppName));
```

but its working only in localhost. if am using this code in my cpanel its showing error in "COM" line .

could you please suggest any other code without using COM.

Comment: Googling `php ppt to image` will turn up lots of results

Comment: I have googling but I got com related code

Comment: [Convert ppt/pptx to JPG/PNG using PHP on apache server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15936010) might work

Comment: Also [Convert ppt to jpg](http://superuser.com/q/388350) if you have OpenOffice installed on your server.

Comment: Hi i need php code for converting ppt to image and running in my cpanel hosted server.

Comment: yes it is cpanel server. so please guide for this.

Comment: The code you are looking for may not exist. It's not a trivial task and may be impossible without the help of an external app running on the server.

Comment: You must run it on Windows with PowerPoint installed. I guess that your server environment uses LAMP.

Comment: The code you have supplied can only work on a Windows system as it depends on COM. If you want to do this on a non-windows server, there does not appear to be any code right now.

Comment: if I used the COM, how to run in my cpanel because If i put above the code in my cepanel server it shows error the http://puthuvannam.com/PV/phpjpg/